# How to add condition if object empty on the vue.js 2?

Tags: object, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component is like this :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="!list">No results.</div>
        <div v-else class="panel-group" v-for="item in list">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        computed: {
            list: function() {
                return this.$store.state.order.list
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The result of `console.log(this.$store.state.order.list)` is like this :

[image]

Seems it's a object

I try like that, but when the object empty, it not display `<div v-if="!list">No results.</div>`

Is there anyone who can help me?

**Update** :

If no data, the result of `console.log(this.$store.state.order.list)` is like this :

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<div v-if="Object.keys(list).length === 0">No results.</div>
```